# Partial class declaration error new WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make a new WPF window open on a button click (within my main window). I am getting this error

Partial declarations of 'KPI_Generator_v3.completedWindow' must not specify different base classes
on line 9 of the new window's XAML.CS

Can you help me fix it and explain what is going on? I am still very new and, from googling for the last hour, am under the impression that this is a very simple error but I can not for the life of me fix it.

Here is my XAML for the new window:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="KPI_Generator_v3.completedWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="completedWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
      <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,82,0,0"    
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Here is my XAML.CS for new Window:

```
using System.Windows;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace KPI_Generator_v3
{

    public partial class completedWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public completedWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now my main window XAML

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="KPI_Generator_v3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="Utilities" Height="538" Width="1000" >
   <Grid Margin="0,0,0,100">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="21,0,0,358">
            <MenuItem x:Name="fileMNU" Header="_File" Width="43" >
                <MenuItem x:Name="exitMNU" Header="_Exit" Click="exit_Click" />
            </MenuItem>
   </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

And finally the XAML.CS of my Main Window

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;




namespace KPI_Generator_v3
{

    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {

        string[] result;
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        string[] fileNameNoExt;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     }
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: make sure there is no other partial class inheriting other then MetroWindow

Comment: Does this mean that I can not use the MahApps library on the new window? Or should I remove the "partial" from "public partial class completedWindow : MetroWindow"

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I appreciate everything you 2!